# How to merge dataframes with unique rows and varying columns/column order?

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

**Q:** how do I merge dataframes with unique rows and varying numbers of shared columns?

#### Background

I have a large number of different datasets of survey respondents
that I want to combine into a single dataframe (or tibble, if
we're using `dplyr`).  Each respondent is unique; no respondent
appears in more than one dataset.

This would be a simple task if each dataset had each variable in
the same column order, because the solution would be:

```
combined <- rbind(df1, df2, df3, dfn)
```

Sadly, that's not the state of these data.  Instead, each dataset
has a variable for respondent ID number, year of survey, country
of survey, and a *varying number of questions that do not appear
in the same column order* in the raw dataset.  They do have the
same *variable names*, however.

#### That question again, given the background

*How do I merge these datasets into a single dataframe, given that
a) each respondent row is unique, b) not all variables appear in
all datasets, and c) not all variables appear in the same column
order?*

#### Some example data

A simple start with just two dataframes (tibbles, actually) is:

```
df1 <-
    tribble(~ rid,  ~ a,  ~ b,  ~ c,
                1, "a1", "b1", "c1",
                2, "a2", "b2", "c2",
                3, "a3", "b3", "c3")

df2 <-
    tribble(~ rid,  ~ a,  ~ d,  ~ c,  ~ e,
                4, "a4", "d1", "c4", "e1",
                5, "a5", "d2", "c5", "e2",
                6, "a6", "d3", "c6", "e3")
```

Respondents are identified by `rid`.  Each question is identified
by one of the other variables.  In this example, questions `a` and
`c` were asked in both surveys, but `b` was asked only in the
first survey, and `d` and `e` were asked only in the second
survey.

The goal is to have respondents in the rows and variables in
columns, filled in with `NA`s when a variable does not appear is a
dataset.

#### What I tried

I'm a bit of a goober with base R's `merge` operations and
`dplyr`'s `*_join` operations.  I'm not even sure this is the
correct way to go about solving this problem, or if "merging" is
even the correct verb.  Therefore, perhaps naively, I tried a
`full_join(df1, df2, by = "rid")`, which yields:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
    rid   a.x     b   c.x   a.y     d   c.y     e
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1    a1    b1    c1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2     2    a2    b2    c2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3     3    a3    b3    c3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4     4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    a4    d1    c4    e1
5     5  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    a5    d2    c5    e2
6     6  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    a6    d3    c6    e3
```

Instead, what I'm trying to get is:

```
    rid     a     b     c     d     e
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1    a1    b1    c1  <NA>  <NA>
2     2    a2    b2    c2  <NA>  <NA>
3     3    a3    b3    c3  <NA>  <NA>
4     4    a4  <NA>    c4    d1    e1
5     5    a5  <NA>    c5    d2    e2
6     6    a6  <NA>    c6    d3    e3
```

#### Another solution that didn't work

I tried the solution in [Simultaneously merge multiple data.frames in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list), but it gave me wonky results:

```
list(df1, df2) %>%
    Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) full_join(dtf1, dtf2, by="rid"), .)
```

Which yields:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
    rid   a.x     b   c.x   a.y     d   c.y     e
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1    a1    b1    c1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2     2    a2    b2    c2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3     3    a3    b3    c3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4     4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    a4    d1    c4    e1
5     5  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    a5    d2    c5    e2
6     6  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>    a6    d3    c6    e3
```

I don't know why `a` and `c` are not merging appropriately.

Comment: Would you have same "rid" in different dataframes?

Comment: @zx8754: I had found that question and tried the solution proposed there,
but it does not merge the shared columns correctly (see edits to post).  That is, 
`list(df1, df2) %>% Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) full_join(dtf1,
dtf2, by="rid"), .)` gives me a 6x8 dataframe (not 6x6) whose
column names are `rid`, `a.x`, `b`, `c.x`, `a.y`, `d`, `c.y`, and `e`.

Comment: @zx8754: the raw, raw data probably has duplicate ID numbers between different datasets, but I can uniqueify them easily enough.

Comment: Maybe simply: `dplyr::bind_rows(df1, df2)` ?

Comment: Please note that the column order itself is not a problem from `rbind` (`rbind(data.frame(a = 1, b = 2), data.frame(b = 3, a = 4))`) - it's when _columns differ_. You may wish to phrase your question accordingly.

Comment: @Henrik: the solution in the post you highlighted works, although it was a little convoluted to find.  (The short version: `rbindlist(list(df1, df2), fill = TRUE)` gets the job done.)  No objections if this post is marked as a duplicate, although the `bind_rows` solution mentioned in the comments also works, is quite simple, and has the added advantage of using only `dplyr` rather than adding `data.table` to the mix.

Comment: @zx8754: yup, `bind_rows` does the job (didn't know that existed).  Please post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: `bind_rows` is part of the linked post, it is used be called `rbind_all`.

Comment: @zx8754 I just pinged Arun in the link that he may wish to update his answer to include `bind_rows` instead.